# How to have both function calls and parenthetical grouping without backtrack

Tags: antlr, antlr3

Is there any way to specify a grammar which allows the following syntax:

```
f(x)(g, (1-(-2))*3, 1+2*3)[0]
```

which is transformed into (in pseudo-lisp to show order):

```
(index 
  ((f x)
    g 
    (* (- 1 -2) 3)
    (+ (* 2 3) 1)
  ) 
  0
)
```

along with things like limited operator precedence etc.

---

The following grammar works with backtrack = true, but I'd like to avoid that:

```
grammar T;

options {
 output=AST;
 backtrack=true;
 memoize=true;
}

tokens {
  CALL;
  INDEX;
  LOOKUP;
}

prog: (expr '\n')* ;

expr : boolExpr;

boolExpr
 : relExpr (boolop^ relExpr)?
 ;

relExpr
 : addExpr (relop^ addExpr)?
 | a=addExpr oa=relop b=addExpr ob=relop c=addExpr
   -> ^(LAND ^($oa $a $b) ^($ob $b $c))
 ;


addExpr
 : mulExpr (addop^ mulExpr)?
 ;

mulExpr
 : atomExpr (mulop^ atomExpr)?
 ;

atomExpr
 : INT
 | ID
 | OPAREN expr CPAREN -> expr
 | call
 ;

call
 : callable ( OPAREN (expr (COMMA expr)*)? CPAREN -> ^(CALL callable expr*)
            | OBRACK expr CBRACK -> ^(INDEX callable expr)
            | DOT ID -> ^(INDEX callable ID)
            )
 ;

fragment
callable
 : ID
 | OPAREN expr CPAREN
 ;

fragment
boolop
 : LAND | LOR
 ;

fragment
relop
 : (EQ|GT|LT|GTE|LTE)
 ;

fragment
addop
 : (PLUS|MINUS)
 ;

fragment
mulop
 : (TIMES|DIVIDE)
 ;

EQ : '==' ;
GT : '>' ;
LT : '<' ;
GTE : '>=' ;
LTE : '<=' ;

LAND : '&&' ;
LOR : '||' ;

PLUS : '+' ;
MINUS : '-' ;
TIMES : '*' ;
DIVIDE : '/' ;

ID : ('a'..'z')+ ;
INT : '0'..'9' ;

OPAREN : '(' ;
CPAREN : ')' ;
OBRACK : '[' ;
CBRACK : ']' ;
DOT : '.' ;

COMMA : ',' ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your grammar:

### 1

Only lexer rules can be `fragment`s, not parser rules. Some ANTLR targets simply ignore the fragment keyword in front of parser rules (like the Java target), but better just remove them from your grammar: if you decide to create a parser for a different target-language, you may run into problems because of it.

### 2

Without the `backtrack=true`, you cannot mix tree-rewrite operators (`^` and `!`) *and* rewrite rules (`->`) because you need to create a single alternative inside `relExpr` instead of the two alternatives you now have (this is to eliminate an ambiguity).

In your case, you can't create the desired AST with just `^` (inside a single alternative), so you'll need to do it like this:

```
relExpr
 : (a=addExpr -> $a) ( (oa=relOp b=addExpr    -> ^($oa $a $b))
                         ( ob=relOp c=addExpr -> ^(LAND ^($oa $a $b) ^($ob $b $c))
                         )?
                     )?
 ;
```

*(yes, I know, it's not particularly pretty, but that can't be helped AFAIK)*

Also, you can only put the `LAND` token in the rewrite rules if it is defined in the `tokens { ... }` block:

```
tokens {
  // literal tokens
  LAND='&&';
  ...

  // imaginary tokens
  CALL;
  ...
}
```

Otherwise you can only use tokens (and other parser rules) in rewrite rules if they really occur inside the parser rule itself.

### 3

You did not account for the unary minus in your grammar, implement it like this:

```
mulExpr
 : unaryExpr ((TIMES | DIVIDE)^ unaryExpr)*
 ;

unaryExpr
 : MINUS atomExpr -> ^(UNARY_MINUS atomExpr)
 | atomExpr
 ;
```

---

Now, to create a grammar that does not need `backtrack=true`, remove the `ID` and `'(' expr ')'` from your `atomExpr` rule:

```
atomExpr
 : INT
 | call
 ;
```

and make everything passed `callable` optional inside your `call` rule:

```
call
 : (callable -> callable) ( OPAREN params CPAREN -> ^(CALL $call params)
                          | OBRACK expr CBRACK   -> ^(INDEX $call expr)
                          | DOT ID               -> ^(INDEX $call ID)
                          )*
 ;
```

That way, `ID` and `'(' expr ')'` are already matched by `call` (and there's no ambiguity).

---

Taken all the remarks above into account, you could get the following grammar:

```
grammar T;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
 // literal tokens
 EQ     = '==' ;
 GT     = '>' ;
 LT     = '<' ;
 GTE    = '>=' ;
 LTE    = '<=' ;
 LAND   = '&&' ;
 LOR    = '||' ;
 PLUS   = '+' ;
 MINUS  = '-' ;
 TIMES  = '*' ;
 DIVIDE = '/' ;
 OPAREN = '(' ;
 CPAREN = ')' ;
 OBRACK = '[' ;
 CBRACK = ']' ;
 DOT    = '.' ;
 COMMA  = ',' ;

 // imaginary tokens
 CALL;
 INDEX;
 LOOKUP;
 UNARY_MINUS;
 PARAMS;
}

prog
 : expr EOF -> expr
 ;

expr
 : boolExpr
 ;

boolExpr
 : relExpr ((LAND | LOR)^ relExpr)?
 ;

relExpr
 : (a=addExpr -> $a) ( (oa=relOp b=addExpr    -> ^($oa $a $b))
                         ( ob=relOp c=addExpr -> ^(LAND ^($oa $a $b) ^($ob $b $c))
                         )?
                     )?
 ;

addExpr
 : mulExpr ((PLUS | MINUS)^ mulExpr)*
 ;

mulExpr
 : unaryExpr ((TIMES | DIVIDE)^ unaryExpr)*
 ;

unaryExpr
 : MINUS atomExpr -> ^(UNARY_MINUS atomExpr)
 | atomExpr
 ;

atomExpr
 : INT
 | call
 ;

call
 : (callable -> callable) ( OPAREN params CPAREN -> ^(CALL $call params)
                          | OBRACK expr CBRACK   -> ^(INDEX $call expr)
                          | DOT ID               -> ^(INDEX $call ID)
                          )*
 ;

callable
 : ID
 | OPAREN expr CPAREN -> expr
 ;

params
 : (expr (COMMA expr)*)? -> ^(PARAMS expr*)
 ;

relOp
 : EQ | GT | LT | GTE | LTE
 ;

ID     : 'a'..'z'+ ;
INT    : '0'..'9'+ ;
SPACE  : (' ' | '\t') {skip();};
```

which would parse the input `"a >= b < c"` into the following AST:

[image]

and the input `"f(x)(g, (1-(-2))*3, 1+2*3)[0]"` as follows:

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason people don't generally put all tokens in the tokens block?

Comment: @luxun, you can only put literal tokens in it, so a rule like `Bs : 'B'+;` can't be put in the `tokens { ... }` block. But it doesn't really matter where you put literal tokens: as lexer rules or in `tokens { ... }` (unless you're "injecting" foreign tokens in rewrite rules, of course).

Comment: @Bart_Kiers: How would I implement a function literal into this scheme that looks like `OPAREN ( ID (COMMA ID)+ )? CPAREN OBRACE stmt* CBRACE`?

Comment: @luxun, change `callable` so that it accepts not one `expr` in `OPAREN expr CPAREN` but more. And add `OBRACE stmt* CBRACE` to the right hand side of the `call` rule. If you run into problems, please create a new question: these comment boxes are ill suited for extensive Q&A's. Good luck!

Comment: Don't quite understand what you're saying, so please help me further in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762153/adding-function-literals-while-abstaining-from-backtracking.